# pass two variables with connected web parts

Tags: web-part

Sharepoint 2010 - 
Can you pass two variables between web part connections?  I have 4 web parts that I need to select the list items to display in each individual web part when either of the 2 variables is input into the search field on the web page.

THanks for your input and advice.

-RT

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is No.

A webpart can only be connected to another webpart through one connection type and it can have only one connection type.

You cannot establish two connections between same instance of Provider and Consumer webpart. But, You can connect a provider web part with two instance of same consumer webpart (if the provider expose two connections points).

A web part provider can make multiple connection points available, while a web part consumer can consume multiple provider connection points.